# Google Colab TPU / NONE

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have used Google Colab with runtime type NONE. I have created a lot of files (19000)on virtual machine drive. Now I have changed runtime type to TPU, and I haven't seen my files.

Is there any tricks to share/copy my files from NONE vm to TPU vm?[image]

Answer (score 0):

they are separate instances so you wont be able to copy them over directly, what you can do is mount your drive in NONE content and is !cp -r to copy over the 19000 files to your google drive then switch over to TPU then mount drive again and use !cp -r again to copy them to TPU vm.